# Could a VPN server hide all user's information?

Tags: vpn, proxy, anonymity

I'm trying to access some server using VPN(Or generally say, proxy). But sometimes the server could detect that I'm behind a proxy(And sometimes not).

So I'm wondering what information could be leaked so that the server can determine that there is a proxy.

I have tried the following:

1. Cookies
2. Browser cache
3. DNS entry

As far as I know, a VPN can hide all user's information so there won't be any information which can be used to identify the real user.

Am I wrong?

PS: I have to login the server, so server may still hold some information in session. But it cannot explain why sometimes the server cannot detect my proxy.

PPS: I'm not sure that this is the right SE site to ask this question, if I'm wrong, please let me know.

Comment: Your question has a fundamental misunderstanding. VPNs cannot and do not "hide all user's information". They protect from MITM attacks at crappy hotel WiFi. Even with a VPN, a remote site can reliably identify your exact individual hardware with 100% accuracy via AudioContext fingerprinting.

Comment: This hears meaningful, I will dive into AudioContext fingerprinting. Thanks.

Comment: AudioContext fingerprinting is not the only way to identify a device. Browser fingerprinting in general is a powerful way to track people. If you want to avoid that, you should use [Tor Browser](https://www.torproject.org) which makes an attempt to prevent these issues.

Comment: A VPN protects you against threats in between the two VPN endpoints.  It doesn't protect you against threats on your computer, and it doesn't protect you against the server you connect to on the far side of the VPN.  If your connection is an Ethernet cable, a VPN is an armored conduit.  It doesn't stretch the whole length of the cable, and it certainly doesn't shield you from what the other end is plugged into.

Comment: @BenVoigt For a shared VPN (i.e. a VPN where you are not the only member), it may not even do that correctly. Good enough to avoid casual snooping when you're using insecure public WiFi, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A properly setup VPN hides information about the public IP address of the user, not more and in case of improperly setup VPN often less. It does not hide any cookies, browser history, hardware capabilities, internally used IP addresses or even the existence of internal systems which can be detected through various means. This means fingerprinting of the browser and of the environment it is running in it is still possible. Side-channel and timing based fingerprinting of the browsers state regarding for which sites HSTS information are stored, where the user is currently logged in and similar are also still possible.

But the most common leakage are probably still improperly configured or improperly designed VPN. A DNS based information leak happens for example if the locally used DNS server still points to some internal IP address (typically the home router) or in case of SOCKS proxies (which are not real VPN but often used for privacy)  when the client is not using the ability of SOCKS5 to resolve DNS but does it outside (default setting for Firefox). There are sites like [dnsleaktest.com](https://www.dnsleaktest.com/) which help in detecting such a leak.

Another major problem is a missing support for IPv6 in some VPN. Thus if the network is connected with IPv6 and IPv6 capable sites are visited this traffic will completely bypass the VPN. There are sites like [ipv6leak.com](http://ipv6leak.com/) which help in detecting such a leak.

Comment: Oh oh, after testing, I found my dns is really leaking... Thanks a lot! Although I still need to check other leakage.

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you but I am wondering one question that how could a server detect my DNS leakage? As I know, even if I use my real IP address to request DNS server, how could the target server know this request?

Comment: @Sraw: Please don't ask new questions inside a comment. Ask a new question instead.  But a short search for [how does dns leak test work](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+does+dns+leak+test+work) might already answer your question.

Comment: Thank you. I've considered asking a new question but I'm not sure that wether this new question is a part of current question.

Comment: @Sraw: Your current question was if a VPN could hide all user information.  Your question in the comment was how sites detecting a DNS leak work technically. I think the new question is different enough from the original one.

Comment: Yep, I am new in this area. Thanks for your patience.